# Absolute-difference function for std::size_t

Tags: c++

Because `std` doesn't provide an overloaded version of `std::abs` for `std::size_t`, I built a version to calculate distance between unsigned numbers.

It subtracts the smaller one from the larger one, to prevent a negative result, since in unsigned integer it would wrap around.

```
std::size_t size_type_abs(std::size_t a, std::size_t b)
{
    return std::max(a, b) - std::min(a, b);
}
```

Is this implementation correct and efficient?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This function computes absolute difference, not absolute value, so it shouldn't be called `abs`. `absolute_difference`? `size_diff`?

What will you use this function for? Are you using `size_t` for something other than sizes, so an absolute difference is meaningful?

`std::max(a, b) - std::min(a, b)` is harder to read than a simple conditional:

```
return a > b ? a - b : b - a;
```

This function isn't specific to `size_t`; it can be defined for any type that supports comparison and subtraction:

```
template<typename T>
T abs_diff(T a, T b) {
  return a > b ? a - b : b - a;
}
```

If you do want to define it only for `size_t`, `using std::size_t` would save some repetitions of `std::`.

Comment: "`std::max(a, b) - std::min(a, b)` is harder to read than a simple conditional" seems false to me. For example its much easier to see the difference between `std::max(a, b) - std::min(a, b)` and `std::min(a, b) - std::max(a, b)` than between `a > b ? a - b : b - a` and `a > b ? b - a : a - b`, or `b > a ? a - b : b - a`, or `b > a ? b - a : a - b`.

Comment: There exists a proposal for `abs_diff`, unfortunately it doesn't seem to have had follow up https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4318.pdf - https://www.meetingcpp.com/blog/items/c17-library-papers-for-cologne-part-ii.html

Comment: Your function could be improved by adding `const` to the input parameters as they are not going to be modified.

Comment: `using std::size_t;` would need to be in the containing scope (namespace, or even translation-unit) to shorten the code, and the consequences of that are probably not worth the small benefit.

Answer (score 7):

This probably isn't the most efficient method possible. In particular `std::min` and `std::max` are typically implemented something like:

```
template <class T>
T std::min(T a, T b) { return a < b ? a : b; }

template <class T>
T std::max(T a, T b) { return a < b ? b : a; }
```

So, the overall code looks something like this:

```
std::size_t size_type_abs(std::size_t a, std::size_t b) { 
    return a < b ? a : b - a < b ? b : a;
}
```

The compiler may (but certainly won't necessarily) recognize that one of these comparisons is redundant. I'd prefer to ensure that only one comparison is done:

```
std::size_t size_type_abs(std::size_t a, std::size_t b) { 
   return a < b ? b - a : a - b;
}
```

This might be about the same efficiency as your version, or it might be marginally better. I'd be rather surprised to see it any less efficient though. I see little difference in readability between the two, so no real preference on that account.